# Regression with two independent variables - optimize for linear error instead of quadratic error

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, python, least-squares, generalized-least-squares

I am trying to solve a set of linear equations in the form of `ax1 + bx2 = c`, where I know the values for `a`, `b` and `c` and I want to get the `x1` and `x2` values. Usually you'd use a least-squares regression, but that isn't giving me the results I want. I found [this website](http://faculty.cas.usf.edu/mbrannick/regression/Part3/Reg2.html) which explains how to solve for x1 and x2 using least-squares. However, I want to optimize x1 and x2 such that

$$ \sum \limits_{i=0}^{n} c_{i}-a_{i}x_{1}-b_{i}x_{2} = 0 $$

instead of the least-squares solution, which solves for

$$ \sum \limits_{i=0}^{n} (c_{i}-a_{i}x_{1}-b_{i}x_{2})^2 = 0 $$

The data I have is this:

```
0                 * x1  +  0                 * x2  =                 0
0.355116901775958 * x1  +  0.074355530922201 * x2  =  3.70277585006972
0.444418152930507 * x1  +  0.219266287478505 * x2  =  6.06070065351470
0.363145347644357 * x1  +  0.386147834850555 * x2  =  7.11791957320285
0.198903631449205 * x1  +  0.442769595436206 * x2  =  6.38607945041053
0.079946019237193 * x1  +  0.363442774579523 * x2  =  4.55677830027078
0                 * x1  +  0                 * x2  =                 0
```

I tried following the tutorial on the website to get a least-squares approximation like this:

```py
class RegressionInput(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

class RegressionOutput(object):
    def __init__(self, x1, x2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2

# @returns RegressionOutput
def solve_equations(equations):

    num_equations = len(equations)

    c_sum = 0.0
    a_sum = 0.0
    b_sum = 0.0
    ac_sum = 0.0
    bc_sum = 0.0
    ab_sum = 0.0

    for eq in equations:
        c_sum += eq.c
        a_sum += eq.a
        b_sum += eq.b
        ac_sum += eq.a * eq.c
        bc_sum += eq.b * eq.c
        ab_sum += eq.a * eq.b

    c_mean = c_sum / num_equations
    a_mean = a_sum / num_equations
    b_mean = b_sum / num_equations

    # Calculate sum of squares of deviations of data points from their sample mean (DEVSQ)
    devsq_c = 0.0
    devsq_a = 0.0
    devsq_b = 0.0

    for eq in equations:
        devsq_c += pow(eq.c - c_mean, 2)
        devsq_a += pow(eq.a - a_mean, 2)
        devsq_b += pow(eq.b - b_mean, 2)

    # Calculate the x1 and x2 values
    ca = ac_sum - a_sum * c_sum / num_equations
    cb = bc_sum - b_sum * c_sum / num_equations
    ab = ab_sum - a_sum * b_sum / num_equations

    x1 = (devsq_b*ca-ab*cb) / (devsq_a*devsq_b-ab*ab)
    x2 = (devsq_a*cb-ab*ca) / (devsq_a*devsq_b-ab*ab)

    return RegressionOutput(x1, x2)
```

```py
equations = [
    #               a*x1                +  b*x2                 = c
    RegressionInput(0,                     0,                     0),
    RegressionInput(0.355116901775958,     0.074355530922201,     3.70277585006972),
    RegressionInput(0.444418152930507,     0.219266287478505,     6.0607006535147),
    RegressionInput(0.363145347644357,     0.386147834850555,     7.11791957320285),
    RegressionInput(0.198903631449205,     0.442769595436206,     6.38607945041053),
    RegressionInput(0.079946019237193,     0.363442774579523,     4.55677830027078),
    RegressionInput(0,                     0,                     0),
]

output = solve_equations(equations)

print("output:")
print("\tx1: " + str(output.x1))
print("\tx2: " + str(output.x2))
```

Which gives me:

```
x1: 8.271333770943588
x2: 10.714526915345777
```

I know (through experimentation), that the correct values are

```
x1: 9
x2: 10
```

... which is quite a difference! I calculate the error like this:

```py
def calc_error_squared(equations, output):
    error = 0.0
    for eq in equations:
        error += pow(eq.c - (eq.a * output.x1 + eq.b * output.x2), 2)
    return error

def calc_error_normal(equations, output):
    error = 0.0
    for eq in equations:
        error += eq.c - (eq.a * output.x1 + eq.b * output.x2)
    return error
```

... in which case I get:

```
# x1 = 8.271333770943588, x2: 10.714526915345777
error squared: 0.0027779024957681
error normal: -0.020716766062418568
# x1 = 9, x2: 10
error squared: 0.14303258514172026
error normal: -0.009336882536300717
```

So how could I go about optimizing for the linear sum instead of the quadratic sum?

Comment: I think you want the absolute value. Then you’re doing median regression aka quantile regression at the 0.50 quantile aka MAE (mean absolute error) regression.

Comment: No, I've had someone correct me on this: I'm looking for a way to optimize for the least absolute error, i.e. least absolute deviations, i.e. LAD.

Comment: How is that different?

Comment: LAD doesn't divide by the number of points, that's about it. However, this entire question can probably be resubmitted with the title of "how do I build a LAD solver", to which there are many answers on the internet already.

Comment: You can use the quantile regression tools build into common software packages like quantreg in R or statsmodels in Python.